# MySQL Incorrect syntax near 'MODIFY'

Tags: mysql, sql

someone know what is bad?

```
ALTER TABLE "stats"
  MODIFY "id" int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=2;
COMMIT;
```

```
Incorrect syntax near 'MODIFY'.
```

idk what is wrong, someone can help?

Comment: You forgot to add `MODIFY COLUMN`

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava This question is about MySQL, not SQL-Server.

Comment: @Cursed `COLUMN` is optional.

Comment: Use correct quote char.

Comment: Double quote can be used for column names in Microsoft SQL Server but not in MySQL. You can remove quotes or put back tick instead, then it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using double quotes use backticks, also an Auto_increment must be PRIMARY KEY

```
ALTER TABLE `stats`
  MODIFY `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, AUTO_INCREMENT=2;
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 1):

short answer: instead of **"** (double quotes ) use **`** (backticks)

Long answer :

Backticks are used in MySQL to select columns and tables from your MySQL source. In the example below, we are calling to the table titled Album and the column Title. Using backticks we are signifying that those are the column and table names.

```
ALTER TABLE `stats`
MODIFY `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=2;
COMMIT;
```

or, The backticks for column names may not be necessary though.

```
ALTER TABLE stats
MODIFY id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=2;
COMMIT;
```